# OpenCV GPU library usage

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

Can OpenCV GPU libraries be used in non Nvidia GPUs? I ask this since the FAQ page refers to CUDA. Can it be used in Videocore GPU core?

Answer (score 5):

> The OpenCV GPU module is a set of classes and functions to utilize GPU
>   computational capabilities. It is implemented using NVIDIA* CUDA*
>   Runtime API and supports only NVIDIA GPUs.

From: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks Abid. So is there a way to capture video frames from a webcam using openCV and route tthe processing through a non Nvidia GPU. the video stream is very laggy and i thoght using the GPU might increase the processing speed.

Comment: Actually i haven't used GPU version myself. But there is a tutorial on video here. You can check that : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/gpu/gpu-basics-similarity/gpu-basics-similarity.html#gpubasicssimilarity

Comment: Yup, OpenCV "GPU" is sadly CUDA-only. FYI there is a branch of OpenCV with OpenCL acceleration that I looked at in the spring, but it didn't really seem very usable yet.

Comment: OpenCV+OpenCL is still in development stage. According to developers latest meeting notes(two days ago), it have been moved to trunk now. `The module contains some simple and fairly complex algorithms (like stereo correspondence, 
face detection) accelerated using OpenCL.` And they also said they have tested in dedicated graphics card. So we hope it will be released soon.

Comment: Opencv has now released the ocl mod. It provides a small speed boost with my HD6950.